# Key Error in Python string with format call

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

The following code gives an error:

```
filename='foo.txt'
sed_str = 'PROJECT_DIR=\$\{PROJECT_DIR:-{}\}'.format(filename)
print (sed_str)
```

Results in:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-12-9ac4d7cde75e> in <module>()
      1 filename='foo.txt'
----> 2 sed_str = 'PROJECT_DIR=\$\{PROJECT_DIR:-{}\}'.format(filename)
      3 print (sed_str)

KeyError: 'PROJECT_DIR'
```

Why am I seeing a KeyError?

Comment: The `{....}` are being interpreted as format specifiers.

Comment: Escape your braces: `'s#PROJECT_DIR=\$\{{PROJECT_DIR:-.*\}}#PROJECT_DIR=\$\{{PROJECT_DIR:-{0}\}}'.format('filename')`

Comment: f-strings might make your string building more readable: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

Comment: Yes. They were lost to an earlier attempt to debug this.

Comment: BTW. I do not agree that this is a duplicate.  Yes the other link gives information needed to answer the question, but that answer has nothing to do with dictionaries or key errors.  So this is a special case, but no duplicate.

I could not find the other answer using the error messages that were presented to me.  Again, not a duplicate since one cannot find the information through this error message path.

Comment: The question that you asked has nothing to do with dicrionaries too. You should escape ‘{‘ and ‘}’ special characters in your string as done in the duplicate question and you are good to go. I reopened the question per your request however that has been answered on SO before.

Comment: I have to agree that the duplicate is appropriate. It's the same issue with the same `KeyError` and the same solution.

Comment: I think the solution here is for me to simplify the original question to highlight the KeyError.

It's true that the solution is properly escaping the curly braces, but I think others will accidentally see the key error and this would be helpful.

@ozgur, if you don't think it would be helpful, I'm happy to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in the comments to your questions, you need to escape the curly braces that are not part of what needs to get formatted. Here is an example solution to the problem you are having:

```
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:57:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> sed_str = 's#PROJECT_DIR=\$\{PROJECT_DIR:-.*\}#PROJECT_DIR=\$\{PROJECT_DIR:-{0}\}#'
>>> print(sed_str)
s#PROJECT_DIR=\$\{PROJECT_DIR:-.*\}#PROJECT_DIR=\$\{PROJECT_DIR:-{0}\}#
>>> sed_str = 's#PROJECT_DIR=\$\{{PROJECT_DIR:-.*\}}#PROJECT_DIR=\$\{{PROJECT_DIR:-{0}\}}#'.format('filename')
>>> print(sed_str)
s#PROJECT_DIR=\$\{PROJECT_DIR:-.*\}#PROJECT_DIR=\$\{PROJECT_DIR:-filename\}#
>>>
```

If you have one of the latest versions of Python, you might want to consider using `f''` strings instead to create your `sed_str` variable:

```
>>> path = 'filename'
>>> sed_str = f's#PROJECT_DIR=\$\{{PROJECT_DIR:-.*\}}#PROJECT_DIR=\$\{{PROJECT_DIR:-{path}\}}#'
>>> print(sed_str)
s#PROJECT_DIR=\$\{PROJECT_DIR:-.*\}#PROJECT_DIR=\$\{PROJECT_DIR:-filename\}#
>>>
```

Comment: BTW. The same error happened with f-strings which is why I took them out while trying to figure this out.

Comment: @RaySalemi Did you have any trouble running the exact same code as shown above?

Comment: no the answer was the correct one.  I have to admit I didn't know about {{ and }}.

Comment: I've edited your answer to match the simplified question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `{{` and `}}` to escape curly braces in a format string:

```
filename='foo.txt'
sed_str = 'PROJECT_DIR=\$\{{PROJECT_DIR:-{}\}}'.format(filename)
print (sed_str)
```

Gives:

```
PROJECT_DIR=\$\{PROJECT_DIR:-foo.txt\}
```